# htaccess redirect when https host with full uri including search an hash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, iframe

I have activated a shared SSL on my domain.

I am attempting to redirect if the calling host is HTTPS and is attempting to load one of my pages in an iframe.

Let's assume my webpage is:

```
http://bitbenderz.com/chartticker/?symbol=msft
```

Now your HTTPS page wants to use my webpage in an `<iframe>` by calling it with:

```
https://bitbenderz.com/chartticker/?symbol=msft
```

I want to redirect to ... `https://bitbenderz.websitesource.net/chartticker/?symbol=msft`

I also need to remove any WWW before the domain name.

Thank you, in advance, for your valued assistance!

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bitbenderz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://bitbenderz.websitesource.net%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you.  While that does work, is there any way to bypass the SSL certificate warning? Since my domain uses a SHARED SSL ... https://bitbenderz.com/ does not have a certificate.

Comment: Certificate Warning cannot be fixed by rewrite rule actually since SSL cert negotiation happens before mod_rewrite is even invoked.